# Do I declare my laptop to customs in China

Tags: customs-and-immigration, china

I’m going to be moving to China in September for a year to work.  Obviously I will have the proper work visa and get my residents permit their and so on.

When I arrive at customs do I declare my laptop and phone because it’s over 2000 RMB? Because I’m bringing it back and not keeping it in the territory like it says I would presume I don’t?

Answer (score 2):

No you do not need to declare your laptop phone etc when coming to China unless they are new and still in the box then you might have to explain to customs if you bring them to sell you n the country.

If they are your normal working tools then there is no need to declare them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but I may think that you should, especially if it a particular laptop, otherwise they will be thinking that you want to import or export some sensible or very peculiar data in or out of the country, and I don't think they're going to be dealing nice with you in case of suspect, especially Chinese authorities. Play safe, just my 2 cents.

Comment: Sorry this answer is totally wrong, the Chinese customs you will find in reality care very little about what passes through there at airports, I once even carried 5x the amount of allowed cash and the customs took it out of the bag looked for drugs put it back in and sent me on my way, your mileage might wary of course

Comment: My answer was not from a expert point of view; because, as in the answer itself, I mentioned that I'm not an expert, but just adviced to play safe. I expected that Chinese official were scrupulous in these things like the UAE or Saudi Arabia (you can't play smart with Saudi authorities, and if you do, you know who's the winner...) and I thought the rest of Asia was like that, apart India.